# How does PHP detect that a session has timed out?

Tags: php, session

I'm wondering how PHP detects that a specific session has timed out.

In detail: I'm using the default (file based) session handler, with a default session lifetime and so on. Everything in php.ini is on default.

If now a session is started, PHP does  a check (depending non session.gc_divisor and session.gc_probability) if there are any timed out sessions. But from where does get PHP the last session access time from the sessions to check against?

The session file itself contains only the workload, e.g. `x|i:1;` for a `$_SESSION['x'] = 1;`, so there is no information about the last session access time.

I think that there are no in-memory information related to session start times as the sessions are still working after a full server restart.

So, where does PHP get the information from? Is it comparing the mtime/ctime of the session file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP's default session handler stores the $_SESSION data in a file using `serialize()`, in the directory specified by `session.save_path`. Generally the filename looks something like `$filename = 'sess_' . session_id()`.

Since it's just a file, PHP can use the file's mtime (time of last modification) to determine which session files are stale. Basically it'll grab all the session files whose mtime exceeds the `session.gc_maxlifetime` value and `unlink()` them. As you've said, the probability of the cleanup occuring is governed by the `session.gc_*` ini variables.

Now, if you create your own session handlers with `session_set_save_handler()`, this is all out the window, and you've now got control over how sessions are stored and cleaned up, but this does explain the default behavior.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. You wrote "PHP can use the file's mtime". I'm pretty sure that this is the way PHP works with the default file based session handler, but is there any official statement about this?

Comment: No, but you can always check the php source if you awnt to be sure. Since the 'time-of-last-usage' is not encoded into the session data itself, the session file's mtime is the only other place such information is available. PHP doesnt maintain a database of mtimes elsewhere - if it did, there'd be config options to specify where/how that data would be kept.

Comment: hoped that there would be an easier way than looking into the sources ;) But you're right. There are no options for the mtimes, so there seems to be nothing but the file's mtime. Thanky you.

Comment: you can read about mtime [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) 2nd note

Comment: It's worth noting that PHP touches the file every time you read from session: $_SESSION['foo'];